# How to print something only if a function called is true ten times python

Tags: python

Hi :) my question is basically what the title says. How do i create a function that calls another function ten times and only if all those times the function2 returns True function 1 prints “good job”

For example:

```
  def function_one(s) #returns true if string is increasing
      x = all(x <= y for x, y in itertools.pairwise(seq))
      return x
```

Function 2 should only print good job if function one returns true when called ten times.
I tried:

```
  s = random.randint(0,10)
  for i in range (10):
       if function_one(s) == True:
            print (“Good job”)
```

But this prints it the second function one is true, no matter how many other falses there were prior. Please help :)

Comment: Where does the `seq` in the first function come from?

Comment: function_one's argument s does not seem to have any use; that said, that's not the problem: func2 prints "goof job" each time function_one returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `all` as you did in `function_one`.

Here is an example with a different `function_one`:

```
import random

# make example reproducible
random.seed(0)

# dummy function that returns True with p=0.9
# and also prints an indicator ./× for True/False
def function_one():
    # return True with a probability of 9/10
    n = random.random() > 0.1
    print('⋅' if n else '×', end='')
    return n

def function_two():
    if all(function_one() for _ in range(10)):   # important stuff here
        print('  Good job')
    else:
        print('  failed!')

# repeat the experiment a few times        
for i in range(5):
    function_two()
```

output:

```
⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅  Good job
⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅  Good job
⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅  Good job
⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅×  failed!
⋅⋅⋅⋅×  failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "link" all 10 calls to function 1. For example this should do what you want (I left the s assignment at its original position since I don't know what it's for. Perhaps it should be in the for loop):

```
def func2 ():
    s = random.randint(0,10)
    flag = True
    for i in range (10):
        newtry = function_one(s)
        flag = flag and newtry
    if flag:
        print (“Good job”)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `list` and then `min`:

```
lst=[]
for i in range (10):
     s = random.randint(0,10)
     lst.append(function_one(s))
if min(lst) == True:     
    print (“Good job”)
```

Note that the `random.randint(0,10)` should be inside the loop otherwise you use the same value all the time